# Cannot send QMouseEvent to simulate click inside a flash content in QWebView only under OSX

Tags: macos, qt, flash, qtwebkit, qwebview

I'm using Qt5.4.1 for that I need to use WebKit.
I have a QWebView to display webpages. and I have this piece of code to simulate mouse click:

```
QMouseEvent e(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, pos, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
QApplication::sendEvent(webViewWidget, &e);
```

It works fine on normal webpages. For example it can simulate a click on a link that in google search result page.

It also works fine on Windows for any webpages.

However on Max OSX, I find that it doesn't work within an area that has a flash content. I test with many random online flash games trying to simulate click inside the game. But it doesn't work. The mouse did move to the destination position that I can observe the hover animation (of a flash game button) is on. But it never trigger the click of that button.

The exactly same code works on Windows for the same game.

I also tried to put intervals between the press event and release event, still no hope.

I know this is quite a weird problem but I really want to make this work!

Comment: This could be due to the flash content being in a child widget of the web view. In that case you would have to send it directly to that widget. I don't know whether that might be the case with osx.

Comment: Thanks but I checked that there is no child widget under my webview....